# How can I use this dataset to train a fast.ai model to recognize the pupil-limbus ratio?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, jupyter, fast-ai

UPDATE:

I have created the dataset and run the model here:
https://github.com/woodytwoshoes/Eyetrain.git

---

I'm a medical student trying to produce a machine learning model which recognizes a particular feature of the eye: the Pupil-Limbus Ratio.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4387813/

The images I have saved contain the PLR as calculated by an algorithm. 
GoodPLR_[pupil-limbus ratio is here]_[random number is here]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J1JRFq_l8aFEshFQVrmDhbDLqK7B24c7

The dataset is small, and I understand this will significantly limit the model, but a larger dataset will arrive in a month's time.

Is it correct that I must use a least-squares regression? I know that a classification model is not appropriate.

Perhaps using Jupyter notebook, is there a simple way to set up a fast.ai model to predict PLR based on this dataset?

Thank you.

PLR is useful in head trauma, neurological conditions, and psychiatry.

I used a self-designed algorithm to quickly create a dataset of images with PLR, but is has a high failure rate, and a high error rate. Erroneous PLRs are not contained in the dataset.

I am currently on lesson 1 of fast.ai
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Uzulez6NQRxXoi_iJyyOQaV3bb1nWIcR

I am hoping for a very rough model with a high error rate due to small dataset. But it is something I can improve later as more data arrives.

Answer (score 0):

The suitable way would be to use a Conv-Net using transfer learning. Fast-Ai provides for transfer learning in the first lesson itself..they use resnet30. Follow detailed notes of the lectures and the notebooks..your exact problem is not very clear though..do mention in detail